# Images not showing correctly in Ionic 3 Slides

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am, actually, facing problems with images in **Ionic 3** due to dimensions changes.
One of my case is to display a bunch of images (with various dimensions).
Here is some code:

**page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let th of ThumbsPaths">
        <ion-img [src]=th></ion-img>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

**page.ts**

```
  ThumbsPaths :String[];

  constructor() {
    this.ThumbsPaths = [
      "assets/images/enpages/1.png",
      "assets/images/enpages/2.png",
      "assets/images/enpages/3.png",
      "assets/images/enpages/4.png"
    ];
  }
```

The problem is that in web browser, everything is fine but when I install in my smartphone, I don't see them or I see them so minimized.

How can I fit the image to see it in the whole screen which is actually the `Slide`?

Comment: The path should be `"../assets/images/enpages/1.png"`

Comment: I see the images but how can play with their dimensions to fit the slides?